# Python equivalent of this Curl command

Tags: python, curl

I am trying to download a file using python, imitating the same behavior as this curl command:

```
curl  ftp://username:password@example.com \
    --retry 999 \
    --retry-max-time 0
    -o 'target.txt' -C -
```

How would this look in python ?

Things I have looked into:

- Requests : no ftp support
- Python-wget: no download resume support
- requests-ftp : no download resume support
- fileDownloader : broken(?)

I am guessing one would need to build this from scratch and go low level with pycurl or urllib2 or something similar.

I am trying to create this script in python and I feel lost..  Should I just call curl from python subprocess ?

Any point to the write direction would be much appreciated

Comment: http://pycurl.io/docs/latest/index.html

Comment: there is a small library which extents requests library https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests-ftp

Comment: @vsminkov yes but it doesn't resume downloads on failure

Answer (score 1):

you can use python's inbuilt ftplib

Here is the code:

```
from ftplib import FTP

ftp = FTP('example.com', 'username', 'password') #logs in

ftp.retrlines() # to see the list of files and directories ftp.cwd('to change to any directory')

ftp.retrbinary('RETR filename', open('Desktop\filename', 'wb').write) # start downloading

ftp.close() # close the connection
```

Auto resume is supported. I even tried turning off my wifi and checked if the download is resuming.

You can refer to /Python27/Lib/ftplib.py for default GLOBAL_TIME_OUT settings.

Answer (score 0):

there is this library for downloading files from ftp server

[fileDownloader.py](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fileDownloader.py/0.2.1)

to download the file

```
downloader = fileDownloader.DownloadFile(‘http://example.com/file.zip’, “C:UsersusernameDownloadsnewfilename.zip”, (‘username’,’password’)) 

downloader.download()
```

to resume download

```
downloader = fileDownloader.DownloadFile(‘http://example.com/file.zip’, “C:UsersusernameDownloadsnewfilename.zip”, (‘username’,’password’)) 

downloader.resume()
```

Comment: I have checked this library but it seems to be broken. Namely when I try "import fileDownloader" or "import filedownloader" module cannot be found. Did you try it ?

Comment: not recently I tried it a while ago. at that time it did work fine.

Comment: do you remember what version you tried ? Or how you imported the file ?

Comment: I am afraid that doesn't solve my problem either  

"As you can see, I'm not been able to detect the timeout and retry the connection, but when i got timeout, I simply reconnect again"